# Rely on ABAddressBook & EKEventKit or roll my own?

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook, eventkit

I'm about to embark on an app that will require scheduling of events for "clients" among other things. I've worked with **ABAddressBook** a bit on a previous project (year ago) so knew then its advantages & limitations. No experience with **Event Kit**.

I believe Apple says if you rely on these frameworks (and data sources) you should only store the `ABRecordID` or `eventIdentifier` in your application...then in the future you'd retrieve the address book object (or the event object) and compare them to some local data before proceeding?!?

So, if I want to list all a user's clients in the app i'd first build an array of client objects (that contain the full name and an ABRecordID for each client) then fetch each ABRecordID from AddressBook and compare the full name to what I've stored locally and only THEN display each client's name in the table view?

This seems cumbersome...and I haven't even started with the calendar (though EKEventKit docs are light on this info). Is this considered reliable?

Anyone have any advice before I embark along this path?

Comment: Apple's own method (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKParticipantClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) searches against the ABRecord's email address.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this. I did indeed store the `eventIdentifier` on the device then used it to fetch the event. This is risky since the documentation states that if the calendar of an event changes, the eventIdentifier property will most likely change as well. There doesn't seem to be a "sound" method of storing a programmatically created date and fetching it in the future.